# How to have equal spacing between cell elements in table in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am working on a [website](https://jsfiddle.net/t9ms4c65/5/embedded/result) in which I want to have equal spacing between cell elements in mobile view.

The HTML code for that particular section of code where I want equal spacing is:

**HTML code:**

```
<td id="gv-field-6-25" class="gv-field-6-25"></td>

<td id="gv-field-6-29" class="gv-field-6-29">2016</td>
```

**CSS code:**

The complete CSS code which I am using is in order to make cell elements is:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

 .gv-container-2777  th {
    display: none;
  }

  .gv-container-2777  tr + tr {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

 .gv-container-2777 td {
    display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        margin-top: 7.9%;
  }

 .gv-container-2777     td::before {
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 1.6%;
    }


 .gv-container-2777   td:first-child::before {
    content: 'Year Submitted';
  }

 .gv-container-2777    td:nth-child(2)::before {
    content: 'Descriptive Title of Proposal:';
  }

 .gv-container-2777    td:nth-child(3)::before {
    content: 'Name of Institution';
  }

 .gv-container-2777    td:nth-child(4)::before {
   content: 'Awarded'; 

  }

}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS code (**can't change the HTML code as its all coming from wordpress**) so that there is equal spacing between elements before and after the border.

Attached are the screenshots where I want equal spacing before and after the border:

1st Image:

[image]

2nd Image:

[image]

3rd Image:

[image]

4th Image:

[image]

In the above screenshot the spacing is off before and after the border. I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that I can find equal spacing before and after the border.

Comment: The problem comes from your `td::before` `margin-bottom`; the ones that don't have awards don't get this extra margin. Is simply removing that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

1. Give `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` for `.gv-container-2777 td` same value.

   .gv-container-2777 td {

   ```
   margin-top: 5%;
   margin-bottom: 5%;
   ```

   }
2. Remove `margin-bottom` for `.gv-container-2777 td::before`